# Организация работы между БД и веб сервером

Tags: c#, база-данных, веб-программирование, сервер

Допустим, есть БД, заполненная большим количеством объектов.
И на сервер можно послать `GET` запрос на получение всех этих объектов, пусть условно их будет 5 000. Отдать их нужно в формате `JSON`.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно сперва получить эти объекты из базы, а затем сериализовать их в `JSON`? Если так, то как решить проблему очень долгой сериализации такого большого количества объектов?

Спасибо.

Comment: Строго говоря, 5000 - это немного. Хотя, конечно, это зависит от того, что там у вас за объекты. Если их нужно сериализовать, то, видимо, не очень большие. Что касается первого вопроса - то какая БД используется?

Comment: `Если их нужно сериализовать` - я имел в виду "Если их нужно сериализовать в JSON"

Comment: Сериализовать 5000 объектов быстрее, чем вытащить их из БД. Если у вас проблемы с произодительностью, подумайте, что можно закэшировать.